# How do you animate a sin function from list values x and y?

Tags: python-3.x, animation, jupyter-notebook

I have an array of y values in the shape [0:10,0:100] for a moving sin graph at 10 different time steps and I wanted to animate the motion of the change. I'm pulling the array out of a .dat file.

I'm using MacOSX on jupyter notebooks, I have ffmpeg installed and I have had animations work before, but not exactly like this.
I've used the documentation example to structure the code, which was also a sin graph but used a function for the values of y instead of an array.

```py
data = np.loadtxt("data.dat")
n = int(len(data)) # = 21
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2*np.pi), ylim=(0, 1))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,n)
    y = data[i]
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=n, interval=20, blit=True)

anim.save('movie.mp4', fps=30)
```

The error from that code is

`ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

which seems to originate from the `anim.save()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the number of frames in `animation.FuncAnimation` needed to be the same as the number of time steps.